# Typescript Require exported class not yet loaded

Tags: javascript, typescript, requirejs

I have a unit test using jasmine that needs to import the classes it is going to test, so I include them at the top of the file:

```
///<reference path="./player.ts" name="PlayerModule" />

import PlayerModule = require("./player");
```

**However!**

When I come to creating an instance of the class

```
 var player = new PlayerModule.Player(playerData);
```

... I get an error `Module has not been loaded yet [player]`

The player class use the `exports`

```
export class Player {
 //code
}
```

How to I import other classes into classes for use whereby I can instantiate them, in typescript?

Answer (score 0):

You could import your module and the respective Player class via

```
import {Player} from './player';

const player = new Player(playerData);
```

Is it possible that you use `"module": "amd"` in your `tsconfig.json`?

**Edit:** Overlooked your `requirejs` tag :) Could you add some information about your Jasmine / build configuration?